# Use turf.count with turf.buffer dynamically

Tags: javascript, leaflet, buffer

I have this code where I'm trying to create a buffer dynamically from a draggable marker and then count how many points fall insed this buffer. As of now I can drag the buffer around without any problem and the first position of the buffer return the points count. But when I drag the marker the count does not update and also the buffer ends in a layer above the points. Here is the code:

```
 //add marker that is draggable
 var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(39.702475, -104.875398), {
     draggable: true
 });

 //add marker popup
 marker.bindPopup('This marker is draggable!');
 marker.addTo(map);

 //remove old buffers (used when marker is dragged)
 function removeBuff() {
     map.removeLayer(buff);
 };

 //create buffer (used when the marker is dragged)
 function updateBuffer() {
     //Make the marker a feature
     var pointMarker = marker.toGeoJSON();
     //buffer the marker geoJSON feature
     buffered = turf.buffer(pointMarker, 1, 'miles');
     //add buffer to the map. Note: no "var" before "buff" makes it a global variable and usable within the removeBuff() function. 
     buff = L.geoJson(buffered);
     buff.addTo(map);
     console.log(buffered);
 };

 marker.on('drag', function () {
     removeBuff(), updateBuffer()
 });
 updateBuffer();

 //geojson call for points
 var data = L.geoJson(traffacc, {
     pointToLayer: function (feature, latlgn) {
         var popupContect = "<b>Accident Year:</b>" + feature.properties.year_STR;
         return L.circleMarker(latlgn, Style(feature)).bindPopup(popupContect);
     },
 }).addTo(map);

var pt = data.toGeoJSON();

 var countPt = turf.count(buffered, pt, 'description');

 console.log(countPt);

var resultFeatures = pt.features.concat(countPt.features);
var result = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": resultFeatures
};
```

As you can imagine this code is a patchwork of other people's code. Any ideas of how I can achieve the second part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'var CountPt' part of the code (which does the counting of points) needs to be moved to within the updateBuffer function so that it constantly reruns.

```
 function updateBuffer() {
     var pointMarker = marker.toGeoJSON();
     buffered = turf.buffer(pointMarker, 1, 'miles');
     buff = L.geoJson(buffered);
     buff.addTo(map);
     console.log(buffered);
     var countPt = turf.count(buffered, pt, 'description');
     console.log(countPt);
 };
```

Something like this should do the job. At the moment you only run the count once by the looks of it

Perhaps set up a jsfiddle if you need further assistance.

Good luck,
Rowan

Comment: This indeed solve part of my problem. Now, is there anyway to set the buffer to always be on the layer below the points? I tried to create a jsfiddle, but without much luck: https://jsfiddle.net/darkvengers/2den9wj4/

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I removed the style reference and it seems to work fine  https://jsfiddle.net/2den9wj4/1/

Comment: Thanks! How can I set layer order in leaflet? It seems that at first load the buffer is beneath the points, but once it is updated it becomes an upper layer.

Comment: Im not seeing that on the jsfiddle but you can do some basic things setting order of layers http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-bringtofront